# Variance correction for ties in a Wilcoxon signed rank test

Tags: nonparametric

Firstly, from the last page of 
http://www.statstutor.ac.uk/resources/uploaded/wilcoxonsignedranktest.pdf

it said that
"We have one group of 2 tied ranks, so we must reduce the variance by (8−2)/48 = 0.125."

I wondered why (8−2)/48? I guessed there might be some formula for variance correction with tie observations. But I couldn't find any relevant explanation on this. The most close clue I got might from

https://www.jmp.com/support/help/14-2/wilcoxon-signed-rank-test.shtml

[image: The variance of W]

where, as you can see, the correction is -1/24*½\sum di(di+1)(di-1). This doesn't help but make me even more confused...
By the way, why the correction for zero observations is -1/24*d0(d0+1)(2d0+1)?

Could someone please help explain these mystery (8−2)/48, -1/24*½\sum di(di+1)(di-1) and -1/24*d0(d0+1)(2d0+1) parts?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: **If you would quote your reference fully, the connection would be evident.**  It says to reduce the variance by $(t^3-t)/48.$  Writing $d_2=t$ to match the formula you display, you can see that $$\frac{1}{24}\left[\cdots -\frac{1}{2} d_2(d_2+1)(d_2-1)\right] = -\frac{d_2^3-d_2}{48}=-\frac{t^3-t}{48}.$$

Comment: Yes, you're right! Then my question should be: why this formula in the first place...Thank you very much!